# CListCtrl::InsertItem() causes deadlock when given iIcon of icon that app can't get on WIndows 11

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, icons, windows-11

I have a legacy app that have a dialog with `CListCtrl` that represents files(with icons) in some folder. And when folder contains files of specific extentions(whitch affects icon) App got stuck after I call InsertItem() for that file.

What can I do to prevent that deadlock or can I use icon handlers instead of indexes?

There is what i do:

In background thread I get vector with files info and do foreach. On each iteration I call `SHGetFileInfo` for given filename to get a system index of an icon that associate with that filename and call `m_pListCtrl->InsertItem()`

sample code:

```cpp
m_fiVector = getFilesInfo();
for (int i = 0; i < m_fiVector.size; ++i){

  SHFILEINFO sfi;
  sfi.iIcon = 0;

  SHGetFileInfo(m_fiVector[i].Name,
    (m_fiVector[i].isDir) ? FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY : FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    &sfi, sizeof(sfi), SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_USERFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_SMALLICON
  );

  int pos = m_pListCtrl->InsertItem(m_pListCtrl->GetItemCount(),
    m_fiVector[i].Name,
    sfi.iIcon
  );
  
  m_pListCtrl->SetItemText(pos, 0, m_fiVector[i].Name.c_str());
}
```

That worked fine until I updated to Windows 11 and opened folder with some .ps1 files, thats where deadlock happend.

I figured out that on windows 10(and earlier, i suppose) `SHGetFileInfo` returns `sfi.iIcon` from some system index list, but on windows 11 it return some SHGetFileInfo-Caller-App-based index.
I wrote simple cosole app to demonstrate that behavior. There is screenshots of two runs with different SHGetFileInfo call orders:

- [Windows10 run  example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEALQ.png) - icon indexes given as is from system
- [Windows11 run  example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJx3J.png) - icon indexes given based on request order from current application

Also as you can see on Windows11 screenshot - icon index for .ps1 for some reason is 0, but in my legacy app it's not. (idk why on console app it's 0 cause i have pwsh installed and in explorer file icon is not blank, so there should be an icon index)

And after I pass that non-zero index to CListCtrl - app stucks. With no errors or something. Also it's stucks not in that background thread on InsertItem but on main thread.
I put some logging and can see that all filenames on vector being processed fine.
I guess it stucks in some internal mfc screenUpdate\paint function because visually .ps1 file doesn't apper on a list(and so does not any of files that processed after it)

So my question is how to prevent that deadlock or is there is another way to get or way to chech\validate icon.

Also it would be nice to have a link to some info about that new icon index behavior on win11, thanks.

Comment: The system image list has been per-app since 2000

Comment: You should manipulate GUI elements only on the main (GUI) thread. Otherwise all kind of multithreading problems may occur. If it has worked before, then just by luck. Instead of directly working with `m_pListCtrl` pointer from worker thread, send (or post) a custom message (`WM_APP + n`) from worker thread, passing the item information through message parameters. Alternatively you might want to use producer/consumer pattern so worker thread isn't slowed down by GUI updates.

Comment: Little update: i tried one-thread approach and bug still was there, so it doesn't matter.
I still do it in two threads, cause one-thread was laggy as hell couse of waiting 
i just added some generic icons for most popular file extentions as a resourece in my app and use it on win11.